# Is possible to use conditions to select and deselect in JavaScript with conditions in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an option list (checkbox) to select. This list is dynamically formed as shown in the code below.

```
if ($data_inteiro_01 <= $data_inteiro_02) {
    if ($parcela[$i] === 0) {
        $display = 'disabled';
    }
} else { //Cota Unica venceu
    if ($parcela[$i] === 0) {
        if ($situacao[$i] <> 'Paga')
            $flagCotaUnica = true;
    }
}   
if ($situacao[$i] <> 'Cancelada' && $flagCotaUnica == false) {
    echo ('<td bgcolor=' . $cor . '><input type="checkbox" onclick="submit.disabled = false;" name="check_list[]" value="' . $i . '" ' . $display . '></td>');
    if ($parcela[$i] === 0) {
        echo ('<td bgcolor=' . $cor . ' align="center">Cota Única</td>');
    } else {
        echo ('<td bgcolor=' . $cor . ' align="center">' . $parcela[$i] . '</td>');
    }
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='center'>$situacao[$i]</td>");
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$dataVenc[$i]</td>");
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$valorReal[$i]</td>");
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$valorCorrigido[$i]</td>");
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$valorPagoFormat[$i]</td>");
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$dataPagto[$i]</td>");
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$valorDdReal[$i]</td>");      
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$dias</td>");
    echo ("<td bgcolor=$cor align='right'>$multaDam[$i]</td>");
}
```

But when using this function in JavaScript my conditions are ignored:

```
if ($data_inteiro_01 <= $data_inteiro_02)
```

I want to click on a specific option to disable or uncheck other options. For this, I got the following code JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function valid_teste(){
    "use strict";

    var marcados = 0;
    var verificaMarcado = function() {
        var $checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

        if( marcados>=1 ) {
            loop($checks, function($element) {
                $element.disabled = $element.checked ? '' : 'disabled';
            });
        } else {
            loop($checks, function($element) {
                $element.disabled = '';
            });
        }
    };
    var loop = function($elements, cb) {
        var max = $elements.length;
        while(max--) {
            cb($elements[max]);
        }
    }
    var count = function($element) {
        return $element.checked ? marcados + 1 : marcados - 1;
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var $checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        loop($checks, function($element) {
            $element.onclick = function(){
                marcados = count(this);
                verificaMarcado();
            }
            if($element.checked) marcados = marcados + 1;
        });
        verificaMarcado();
    }
}());
</script>
```

Called by section:

```
<form id="frm_autonomo_iss" name="frm_autonomo_iss" action="gera_dam_iss.php" method="post" accept-charset=utf-8 onsubmit="return valid_teste();">
```

It's possible to do this without ignoring the conditions that are in PHP?

Comment: PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side. Any condition existing in PHP has already been resolved by the time it reaches the JavaScript.

Comment: I don't see that condition anywhere in the JavaScript code.  Maybe that's why it's ignored?

Comment: I believe so @David, but I'm not knowledgeable enough in JS. Have any tips?

Comment: @Deb: I suppose a tip would be to start with some introductory tutorials on JavaScript?  It's not really clear what the problem is here.  Where in all this code is something not working as expected?

Comment: Yes @David, without JS some options are presented in disabled screen. When I add the JS all options are enabled ignoring that should be disabled by default.

Comment: @Deb: Your browser very likely has debugging tools.  (Firebug, Chrome tools, etc.)  Step through the JavaScript in that debugger and determine where specifically it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is that you would like to pass some information from the PHP code to the browser so that the javascript code can make use of it.

This is possible in a number of ways but the simplest way even though it is not the most elegant way is to echo out a `<script>..</script>` containing the data you want to pass. Because of the global nature of javascript variables they will be available when your validation script runs.

So for example you could do this before you run this code

```
if ($data_inteiro_01 <= $data_inteiro_02) {
    if ($parcela[$i] === 0) {
        $display = 'disabled';
    }
```

So add this

```
// assuming that $data_inteiro_01/02 are numeric
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var data_inteiro_01 = ' . $data_inteiro_01 . ';';
echo 'var data_inteiro_02 = ' . $data_inteiro_02 . ';';
echo '</script>';

if ($data_inteiro_01 <= $data_inteiro_02) {
    if ($parcela[$i] === 0) {
        $display = 'disabled';
    }
```

Now in your existing javascript you can use the js variables `data_inteiro_01 and data_inteiro_02`

This may not be the most appropriate place to do this in your script but I dont have much to go on. Oh and by the way the script block does not have to be in the `<head>` section of the page, it can go anywhere as long as it does not break any HTML syntax.

Comment: I did what you @RiggsFolly suggested but it worked. The syntax is correct?  - if(situacao == "Devendo Diferença"){... - This is another condition.

Comment: I have to say _WHAT DID NOT WORK_ maybe you should ask another question and show what you actually did.